# KODI remote isn't working

Tags: linux, firewall, opensuse, remote-control, kodi

I'm trying to correctly configure [KORE](http://kodi.wiki/view/Kore), the official Kodi Remote app for Android, but I'm unable to do so.

My copy of Kodi is installed on a laptop with openSUSE as a base system, and both it and my phone (where the remote control is installed) are connected to the same network from my home router.

I have followed [this guide](http://syncedsynapse.com/kore/kore-faq/) to the letter, but I can't manage to make it work, not automatically and neither by manually entering the required data myself. No matter what I do, the remote app can't see the main Kodi program.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trying, I found that I had to add an exception for my phone IP address to the openSUSE firewall; now it works perfectly.